# Why does my Windows 7 back ground and theme settings reset to default after every reboot?

Tags: windows-7, themes

I have the new Asus G73.  Everything is perfect, but for unknown reasons to me after customizing the background and theme colors, rebooting resets all these back to default (the theme that originally came with the laptop)  Is there a way to stop this madness?

Is there some kind of configuration reset app that runs on start up for Asus computers?  This is my first Asus so I don't know what to expect with the factory bloatware.   No, I don't feel like re-installing bare-bones Windows just to get rid of the bloatware.  Everything works fine except for this one little thing :(  *Sniff*.

Comment: Go to Power4Gear Hybrid and take your settings off of battery saving mode! PROBLEM SOLVED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably third party software is doing this. Go into control panel and the programs/uninstall section and see if there's any application that has like 'Asus wallpaper' or something like that in it's name. Try uninstalling it.

This is just what I think. If something terrible happens don't blame me. :)